# Qt: change color of html tags dosen't work

Tags: c++, html, css, qt

I'm making a text editor in qt where it replaces words with html(to color the html tags) but I can't change the color of the html tags

`string.replace("<home>","<lo style='color:#0066ff;'><home></lo>");`

it works fine with words but when I do it with html tags, it doesn't do anything
I'm don't want highlighting i want to change the color with the css #

how can I fix it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to show html tags, using html highlighting, but qt's html parser will hide all html tags. In order to show them you should replace all `<` with `&#60;` and all `>` with `&#62;`.